# I have to sort numbers using only the min() and the max() functions

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have some homework due and I need to sort number using ONLY the min() and max() function and also using it to find the middle numbers. I have a set of 4 integers. How can I use this code and use it to find the middle numbers without using additional methods.

```
first_integer = input("Please enter the first integer: ")
second_integer = input("Please enter the second integer: ")
third_integer = input("Please enter the third integer: ")
fourth_integer = input("Please enter the fourth integer: ")

integer1 = int(first_integer)
integer2 = int(second_integer)
integer3 = int(third_integer)
integer4 = int(fourth_integer)

integers = (integer1, integer2, integer3, integer4)

min_number = min (integers)
max_number = max (integers)
mid_number_max = min (max(integers),max(integers),max(integers))
mid_number_low = max (min(integers),min(integers),min(integers))
```

When I try execute this with numbers 1,2,3,4 
I get

```
1 1 4 4
```

How can I get

```
1 2 3 4
```

A hint is that I have to remove the lowest and highest numbers and find the minimum and maximum for the rest of the numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got it.

After I looked at the example someone gave me I was able to work it out.

```
first_integer = input("Please enter the first integer: ")
second_integer = input("Please enter the second integer: ")
third_integer = input("Please enter the third integer: ")
fourth_integer = input("Please enter the fourth integer: ")

integer1 = int(first_integer)
integer2 = int(second_integer)
integer3 = int(third_integer)
integer4 = int(fourth_integer)


min_number = min(integer1, integer2, integer3, integer4)
max_number = max(integer1, integer2, integer3, integer4)
mid_number_min = min(max(integer1, integer2), max(integer2, integer3),
                     max(integer3, integer4), max(integer1, integer3),
                     max(integer1, integer4), max(integer2, integer4))
mid_number_max = max(min(integer1, integer2), min(integer2, integer3),
                     min(integer3, integer4), min(integer1, integer3),
                     min(integer1, integer4), min(integer2, integer4))

print (min_number, mid_number_min, mid_number_max, max_number)
```

Results in:

```
1 2 3 4
```

Thank you to whoever attempted to help me either way.

Edit: Thank you to @AChampion for pointing out that I had missed one combination (1,4).

Comment: I believe you are still missing one combination (1 and 4)... try 3, 1, 2, 4 -> 1, 2, 2, 4

Answer (score 3):

Not sure how you expect to get the mid numbers out of the tuple with just `min` `max` across the tuple. You need to check each combination of integers:

```
>>> import itertools as it
>>> integers = 4, 3, 2, 1
>>> (min(integers),
... min(*(max(a, b) for a, b in it.combinations(integers, 2)))
... max(*(min(a, b) for a, b in it.combinations(integers, 2)))
... max(integers)
(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use a `list` instead of a `tuple`, you can do this:

```
integers = [integer1, integer2, integer3, integer4]

min_number = min(integers)
max_number = max(integers)
# Now remove the already found numbers
integers.remove(min_number)
integers.remove(max_number)
mid_number_max = max(integers)
mid_number_min = min(integers)
```

Answer (score 1):

To find out the `max_number` and `mid_number_max`, we first find out the max value of the left 3 elements (`max_left`) and the max value of the right 3 elements (`max_right`). Then compare `max_left` and `max_right`. If they are not equal, it means one of them is the `max_number` and the other is `mid_number_max`. If they are equal, it means the `max_number` locates at `integers[1]` or `integers[2]`. So the `mid_number_max` value should be the `min(integers[1], integers[2])` or `max(integers[0], integers[3])`. So, just pick up the larger one as the `mid_number_max`. The same idea to find out the `min_number` and `mid_number_low`.

```
integers = (3, 1, 2, 4)

max_left = max(integers[0], integers[1], integers[2])
max_right = max(integers[1], integers[2], integers[3])
min_left = min(integers[0], integers[1], integers[2])
min_right = min(integers[1], integers[2], integers[3])

if (max_left != max_right):
    max_number = max(max_left, max_right)
    mid_number_max = min(max_left, max_right)
else:
    max_number = max_left
    mid_number_max = max (min(integers[1], integers[2]), max(integers[0], integers[3]))

if (min_left != min_right):
    min_number = min(min_left, min_right)
    mid_number_low = max(min_left, min_right)
else:
    min_number = min_left
    mid_number_low = min (max(integers[1], integers[2]), min(integers[0], integers[3]))

print (min_number)
print (mid_number_low)
print (mid_number_max)
print (max_number)
```